# Recursive \peek_meaning inside section title

Tags: hyperref, expl3, recursion

I'm trying to do some voodoo with `\peek_meaning`. I want to have a command, `\blubb`, which is sensitive to **repetitions of itself**.

When I write `\blubb{Lorem Ipsum}`, I want the text coloured in **red**, but with `\blubb\blubb{Lorem Ipsum}` I would like the text to be coloured in **blue**. See this working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareRobustCommand\blubb{
    \peek_meaning:NTF \blubb { \colorTwo } { \colorOne }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareRobustCommand\colorOne[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\colorTwo[2]{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}

\begin{document}

Lorem Ipsum \blubb{is red} Dolor Sit \blubb\blubb{is blue}

\section{Lorem Ipsum \blubb{is red} Dolor Sit \blubb\blubb{is blue}}
% ^ does not work with hyperref

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

This works fine, **until** I enable the `hyperref` package. Then I get:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\blubb  ->\peek_meaning:NTF \blubb 
                                   {\colorTwo }{\colorOne }
l.23 ...b{is red} Dolor Sit \blubb\blubb{is blue}}
```

Apparently, the `\blubb` after `\peek_meaning` gets expanded, which leads to a recursion. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \blubb { }
 {
  \peek_meaning_remove:NTF \blubb { \colorTwo } { \colorOne }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand \colorOne { m } {\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand \colorTwo { m } {\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

\begin{document}

Lorem Ipsum \blubb{is red} Dolor Sit \blubb\blubb{is blue}

\section{Lorem Ipsum \blubb{is red} Dolor Sit \blubb\blubb{is blue}}
% ^ does not work with hyperref without warnings

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

But note the console output:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\blubb' on input line 139.
```

This is because `hyperref` makes a bookmark for the `\section` which cannot include the `\blubb` macro. See `hyperref`'s documentation for details. We can use `\texorpdfstring{}{}` to avoid the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \blubb { }
 {
  \peek_meaning_remove:NTF \blubb { \colorTwo } { \colorOne }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand \colorOne { m } {\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand \colorTwo { m } {\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

\begin{document}

Lorem Ipsum \blubb{is red} Dolor Sit \blubb\blubb{is blue}

\section{Lorem Ipsum \texorpdfstring{\blubb}{}{is red} Dolor Sit \texorpdfstring{\blubb\blubb}{}{is blue}}

\end{document}
```

A more convenient way to avoid the warning, however, maybe to use `hyperref`'s hook to disable `\blubb` when necessary. For example (and also using the recommended `bookmark` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \blubb { }
 {
  \peek_meaning_remove:NTF \blubb { \colorTwo } { \colorOne }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand \colorOne { m } {\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand \colorTwo { m } {\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

\makeatletter
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \let\blubb\@firstofone
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem Ipsum \blubb{is red} Dolor Sit \blubb\blubb{is blue}

\section{Lorem Ipsum \blubb{is red} Dolor Sit \blubb\blubb{is blue}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for `\peek_meaning_remove`, this avoids the ugly, inconsistent definition of `\colorXXX`!

Comment: @raffix That wasn't me, I'm afraid.

Comment: @egreg I don't know if pinging this way works, but thank you!

Comment: @cfr Yes, it works. `;-)` Adding a new answer just for fixing a couple of weaknesses was not a choice.

Comment: @egreg So it is better to have the function remove the next `\blubb` than have `\ColorTwo` throw its first argument away? Intuitively that seems better, but I could not explain why.

Comment: @cfr Indeed! You can define `\colorOne` and `\colorTwo` independently of their eventual position in the macro; with the `_remove`, the token is removed *if found* and the proper path is followed. This can be used to check for a third `\blubb`, for instance, without any need for defining differently `\colorThree`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. That makes sense :-).

Answer (score 4):

A different approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\blubb#1{%
  \ifx\blubb#1\relax%
    \def\blubbcolor{blue}\expandafter\blubbhelp%
  \else
    \def\blubbcolor{red}\blubbhelp{#1}%
  \fi%
}
\def\blubbhelp#1{\textcolor{\blubbcolor}{#1}}

\begin{document}

Lorem Ipsum \blubb{is red} Dolor Sit \blubb\blubb{is blue}

Lorem Ipsum \blubb{is red}Dolor Sit \blubb\blubb{is blue}without trailing spaces.

\section{Lorem Ipsum \blubb{is red} Dolor Sit \blubb\blubb{is blue}}
% ^ does not work with hyperref

\end{document}
```

[image]

As cfr rightly notes, `\blubb` generates warnings when used in section titles using `hyperref`, for the purposes of creating bookmarks.  It can be overcome with `\texorpdfstring`, us as follows: `\section{Lorem Ipsum \texorpdfstring{\blubb{is red}}{is red} Dolor Sit \texorpdfstring{\blubb\blubb{is blue}}{is blue}}`, for example.

Comment: Don't you get warnings from `hyperref` with this? I just tried it and I got the same warnings without `\texorpdfstring` as I would get with my code without it.

Comment: @cfr Yes, I get warnings from `hyperref`, related to bookmarks.  But that may not be an issue to the OP, if bookmarks are not of particular interest.

Comment: @cfr As a follow up, the use of `$\alpha$` in a section title will produce a similar warning, for the same reason.  Not everyone is going to recode that as a `\textorpdfstring`.

Comment: You could use `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` instead.

Comment: @ralfix... fixed.