# redefine caret ^ while using mathtools package

Tags: superscripts, catcodes, mathtools, active-characters

consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\newCaret{X}

\catcode`^=\active
\let^=\newCaret

\begin{document}
    $x^2$
\end{document}
```

this works fine, the output is `xX2` as expected.

When I now enable the mathtools package, I obtain the following error:

```
Package: graphics 2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   X
l.33 \catcode`\^^
                 A=\catcode`\%
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

(At the beginning of the `graphics` package, which is used by `mathtools`, there is some catcode-voodoo which seems to conflict with my `\catcode...`)

**possible solution 1**

When I now move the two lines `\catcode...` and `\let...` after the `\begin{document}`, everything is fine again. I need them, however, to stay in the preamble, so this does not solve the problem for me.

**possible solution 2**

I tried wrapping the `\catcode...` and `\let...` inside an `\AtBeginDocument`, but then I get:

```
\Gin@req@height=\dimen123
\Gin@req@width=\dimen124
)
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.11 \begin{document}

Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.12    $x^
         2$
```

**background**

I had the, maybe stupid, idea to simplify the work with upright and italic sub- and superscripts. Until now, I had

```
\newcommand\sub[1]{_\text{#1}}
\let\supremum\sup
\renewcommand\sup[1]{^\text{#1}}
```

for stuff like `k\sub{b}` and `f_i`. In combination with my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329340/recursive-peek-meaning-inside-section-title) I managed get equivalent output with `k__b` and `f_i`: when I double the underscore, I get upright subscripts like with my `\sub` command, and it's super fast to type/change. It also works with superscripts (`^` and `^^`), but only if I change the catcode/let the caret *after* the preamble, so I cannot bundle my code neatly inside a package.

Comment: Changing the category code of `^` in the preamble? Never do it. You can do it in `\AtBeginDocument`, but it requires `\lowercase` trickery. It would be better if you explain your aim in greater detail; for instance, do you need the active `^` only in math mode?

Comment: @egreg: I added more information my question, please see above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the problem in changing the category code of `^` in the preamble? That some packages load files at begin document and these files might contain constructions such as

```
\catcode`\^^A=\catcode`\%
```

that are used to make byte 1 into a comment character or some `` `\^^M `` trickery.

You can set the catcode in the preamble, but delaying it with `\AtBeginDocument` (be sure to do it after loading all packages):

```
\newcommand\NewCaret{X}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\^
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\NewCaret
  \catcode`\^=\active
}
```

The `\lowercase` trick is explained elsewhere on the site, see [The \lowercase trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156759/the-lowercase-trick?s=1|3.1582). On the other hand, if the definition of `^` as an active character is only needed in math mode, it's better to make it only *math active*, see [Underscore in textmode vs mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62705/underscore-in-textmode-vs-mathmode/62707?s=1|3.3138#62707)

```
\newcommand\NewCaret{X}
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\^
\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\NewCaret
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`\^="8000 }
```

Comment: wow, thank you! Concerning my use case with the `^^`, it does not work with your *math active* solution. E.g. `x^^a` would lead to `x!`. Apparently the math active catcode does not alter the special meaning of `^^` as escape sequence, as would a simple `\active`?

Comment: @ralfix Exactly so.